# How to loop through buttons

Tags: swift

I have 16 buttons named like btn1, btn2 etc.. how can i loop through this and set an value to each button?

I have this code:

```
  //set values on the button
        for i in 1..<17{

            var mybutton = "btn" + String(i);
            println(mybutton)
            mybutton.setTitle(String(number), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }

    }
```

but that doesn't work because the software sees it as an string...

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Why is this tagged objective-c?

Comment: Why are you calling 16 buttons `btn1` ... `btn16` rather than, say,  `var btnArray: [UIButton]`, when you could then refer to `btnArray[i]` ?

Comment: Are those buttons created in storyboard or programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can create array of buttons:

```
let array = [btn1, btn2, btn3 ...]

for i in array.count
{
   //do something 
   array[i].setTitle(String(number), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

But if you have a lot of buttons in Interface Builder, the better way to create them programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of ChikabuZ:

If you separately added the buttons in storyboard, I suggest you to create an outlet collection instead: `@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!`.
`CTRL` drag all those buttons in this outlet and you can access the array like ChikabuZ has suggested.

I personally prefer to use a map instead:

```
buttons.map { $0.setTitle(String(number), forState: .Normal) }
```

Comment: One might say `map` shouldn't be used like this, i.e. replacing `for-loops` but I think it looks just cleaner and doesn't really cause any harm.

Answer (score 0):

If you added these in the interface builder and have a reference to the superview, you can assign each of them a tag from 1 to 16  access them using the method "[viewWithTag](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag:)":

```
//set values on the button
        for i in 1..<17{
            var sView = [REFERENCE TO YOUR SUPERVIEW HERE]
            var mybutton = sView.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton?
            println(mybutton)
            mybutton.setTitle(String(number), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }

    }
```